# JPA persistence.xml is not loaded

Tags: jpa

With glassfish, my persistence.xml is not loaded.

```
my.ear
    META-INF/persistence.xml
    lib/entities.jar <!-- no persistence.xml here -->
```

persistence.xml contains

```xml
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
                                 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="xxxPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/xxxDS</jta-data-source>
    <jar-file>lib/entities.jar</jar-file>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

successfully deployed but, I got.

```
Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName xxxPU
```

Thanks.

Comment: How does your jpaEntityManagerFactory bean look like?

Comment: I just found that placing the persistence.xml in META-INF/ of an EAR is not a standard way. Can anybody confirm this?
I created a persistence archive and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to create a .jar file which would contain the persistence.xml file. Then place the jar file in the lib folder. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370043/configure-persistence-units-to-be-available-in-several-jars-of-an-ear/8371383#8371383)